# Error in R-Hive streaming

Tags: r, hive, hadoop-streaming

I am using Hive and R in order to score my machine learning model on a large dataset. However the code is giving the following error.

I have tested the R script separately in my local for any errors and ensured that it is error free. Can somebody give any pointers on the error?

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{},"value":{"_col0":986436000,"_col1":"0","_col2":"0"} at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{},"value":{"_col0":986436000,"_col1":"0"} at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244) ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20001]: An error occurred while reading or writing to your custom script. It may have crashed with an error. at

Answer (score -1):

The above error occurs mostly because of an error in the custom script(R in my case).I figured out that the error was in loading an h2o model object in R script.